# How to match everything within a word

Tags: python, regex, nlp

Sorry if the title is not clear.

More specifically, using python, I want to match `I am (INSERT ANYTHING)ing` like `I am dancing` and `I am walking` but not `I am a student and I like dancing`

If I use `(?<=I am)(.*)(?=ing)` this would match `I am a student and I like dancing`

So namely `(INSERT ANYTHING)ing` should be one word. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: `(?<=I am )[\w-]+ing` or `(?<=I am )[a-z-]+ing` or `(?<=I am )(?i)[a-z-]+ing` if you might have a word in uppercase?

Comment: Could you please explain your expression thank you so much?

Comment: You already know the positive lookbehind, but `[\w-]+` matches one or more word characters (`a-zA-Z0-9_`) or hyphens. `[a-z-]+` on the other hand only matches one or more `a-z` or hyphens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you're describing you don't need the lookbehind, just a pattern before "ing" that doesn't have any spaces:

```
r"I am ([a-zA-Z]+)ing"
```